# Lipschitz monotone functions have inverse a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose we have some $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous and monotone, with $\mathrm{range}(f) = [0,1]$.

What can we say about the size of the set $I = \{t\in [0,1]: f^{-1}(t) \text{ exists and is unique}\}$?

I suspect that it is possible to say that $\lambda(I) = 1$, but I'm not even sure how to show that the set is nonempty. Note that the Cantor staircase is NOT Lipschitz, so it is not a valid counterexample to showing that the set can be empty.

One fact that I tried playing around with the fact that absolutely continuous + monotone implies that $f'$ exists a.e. with $f(1) - f(0) = \int_0^1 f'(t) dt$ implying that $f'(t) >0$ in a set that has positive measure. But I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: No. $f$ need not be strictly monotone. Constant functions are not a valid counterexample because $f$ needs to satisfy $\mathrm{range}(f) = [0,1]$.

Comment: I think I'm reading the question wrong. If $f$ is increasing, then for each $t$, the set $f^{-1}(\{t\})$ is convex, hence an interval. This gives us at most countably many $t$ such that $f^{-1}(\{t\})$ has more than one element, i.e., $f^{-1}(t)$ is not unique. As for existence, surjectivity onto $[0, 1]$ gives us $f^{-1}(\{t\})$ is nonempty for all $t$. Of course, I didn't even refer to Lipschitzness, so that makes me think I'm answering a different question.